# Unsetting persistent system properties

Tags: android, shell, adb

I can set a persistent system property on an Android phone (with appropriate permissions) using `setprop <key> <value>` command:

```
$ adb shell setprop persist.this.is.my.property testing
```

I can then confirm that the property was set:

```
$ adb shell getprop persist.this.is.my.property
testing
```

But I can't remove the key now that it is set (because of the persist at the start of the key it is there after the phone reboots). There is no unsetprop or rmprop or anything similar. Attempting to set the value to nil or null sets that to the value and leaving it empty prompts the help instructions.

Does anyone know how to unset a system property from the command line after it has been set?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Prior to Android 9 Pie, the persistent property is stored as a file and can be removed.

```
rm /data/property/persist.this.is.my.property && reboot
```

Since Android 9 Pie, persistent properties are stored in a single file (commit [16fad42](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/system/core/+/0fac9018f2388f25f5a5778663a14712e75a9903:init/persistent_properties.cpp;bpv=1;bpt=0;drc=16fad42007a7abbc3a1b5727e49c3aad1d8edb97)) and can only be unset.

```
setprop persist.this.is.my.property \"\" && reboot
```

Comment: The correct path is actually /data/property/persist.this.is.my.property

Comment: This is not true anymore.
I added a value via `setprop wrap.path.to.my.app` and it's not listed via `ls /data/property` but still defined if I enter `getprop`

Comment: `setprop wrap.com.secusmart.secuvoice ""` helped for me

Comment: sebweisgerber: the difference is that your property was not in the "persist." family.

Comment: the .data/property directory is for persistent properties only. Other defualt system properties are in the files /dafault.prop and /system/build.prop. All other properties created by user applications are stored in the memory and are not persistent on reboots.

Comment: Can I set build.prop properties with an adb command such as setprop? It doens't seem to work for build.props...

Comment: While, on Android Q, it's a binary file `/data/property/persistent_properties` holding all persist prop. So it's not suitable for Q.

Answer (score 9):

```
adb shell setprop persist.this.is.my.property \"\"
adb shell reboot
```

Changed the property value so it wouldn't be using it's previous value.
Empty quotes("") wouldnt work for me, I had to escape them(this is in bash).

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the property with `adb shell setprop persist.this.is.my.property ""`

Comment: This still leaves the key in the phone's property list, you can see it by typing 'getprop' without specifying a key name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use resetprop -p --delete to remove persistent property

Example:

```
adb shell resetprop --delete persist.this.is.my.property
```

This is the most viable solution as it works unlike "", if you are wondering that why didn't "" work then it was probably used over a non-persistent property and a reboot caused to get it removed.

Comment: Isn't `resetprop` part of Magisk? I can only find it as a symlink to `magisk`.

Comment: See: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/details.html#resetprop

Comment: @Renate you are right, but modifying system properties need root & right now magisk is the only preferred way to root. And when I was stuck with this problem, none of the other answers in this thread worked for me (android 11), so I posted the method I used for future googlers

Answer (score 1):

Editing the file `/data/property/persistent_properties` worked for me (LineageOS 18.1, Android 11), but is probably not worth the risk of corrupting the file... If you go in that direction, I recommend you watch the output of `adb logcat` to see if the persistent_properties code outputs any warnings or errors.

This worked for me:

```
adb root
adb pull /data/property/persistent_properties .
```

Edit the file in your favourite editor. The property will be on its own line, remove that line and the line before (which should be a single character).

```
adb push persistent_properties /data/property/persistent_properties
adb shell
# chmod 0600 /data/property/persistent_properties
# getprop persist.vendor.qfp
```

Take note of the value of `persist.vendor.qfp`; if you don't have this one, select another one from `getprop | grep '^[[]persist\.`. I had "true". Now, to force rewriting the file, change an existing property and change it back to the value it had before you changed it:

```
# setprop persist.vendor.qfp t
# setprop persist.vendor.qfp true
```

The code linked to in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16517098/1214422 (the currently accepted answer) does not seem to write or expect these newlines, so the format of that file must have changed since then.

Answer (score -3):

It works for me.
on macOS:
`echo -e "setprop wrap.$PACKAGE_NAME \"\"\n exit" > .temp
adb shell < .temp
rm ./.temp`

on android:
    `setprop wrap.$PACKAGE_NAME ""`

Answer (score -7):

Just reboot the device, the property will unset.

Comment: No it won't - the persist at the start of the property name makes sure that the property remains even after the phone is reset.

Comment: Prefixing the property with `persist.` does not make it remain after reboot on my phone (LG G6, Android 8.0.0).