# How to set ADT system property in eclipse so it always runs

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, eclipse-adt

I am interested in running

```
  adb shell setprop log.tag.Volley VERBOSE
```

at all times so i can see always see these debug messages inside logcat. Is there somewhere I can perm specify this?  I don't want to open a command prompt every time to set this.

Comment: did i get your question right: you want the eclipse adt LogCat window to always display verbose ? why don't you use the drop down menu inside the eclipse logcat view?

Comment: This option is not provided. As you can see its a custom proeprty. If this property is not set for ADT it will not at all no matter how the filters are set.

Comment: i got your question wrong, sry. it's not about displaying your log, it's about logging in code depending on system props. here is my excuse, i hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440945/android-system-properties-unsetting-them-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 2):

to make my comment clear and visible as answer:

using leading word `persist.` prior to your package should lead to a persistent property.

```
adb shell setprop persist.your.package.name VERBOSE
```

sources: [question in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440945/android-system-properties-unsetting-them-on-the-command-line) and [Mike Lockwoods first answer in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-platform/kkJJJmTfMIo)

i don't know, if this works with AVDs that are restarted and if it's wiped together with the wipe user data of the avd.