# Detailed debug logs with Volley

Tags: android, adb, android-volley, android-logcat

In Restkit on iOS there is a verbose debug option. `RKLogConfigureByName("*", RKLogLevelTrace);`. Does anyone know if there is an equivalent for Volley. Basically I am going straight to the ErrorListener but I get no additional info in LogCat. Both:

```
VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.toString());
```

And:

```
VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
```

Prints:

```
2.onErrorResponse: Error:
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want verbose Log from the volley library, you have to use adb

```
adb -s 42f63b0de7318fe1 shell setprop log.tag.Volley VERBOSE
```

where "`42f63b0de7318fe1`" is your device id which you will get by

```
adb devices
```

If you want to persist this setting use

```
adb -s 42f63b0de7318fe1 shell setprop persist.log.tag.Volley VERBOSE
```

If you have only 1 device you can omit the `-s` argument

see also [How to set ADT system property in eclipse so it always runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797397/how-to-set-adt-system-property-in-eclipse-so-it-always-runs)

Kill and restart your app to apply the setting.

Comment: Thanks. I gave up on Volley months ago and when with loopj's library.

Comment: Np, tought I just leave it here for the next to come :)

Comment: You don't need to pass `-s` if you only have one device (emulator) running

Comment: The persist option did not work at all! So you're stuck with doing this at every debug session, until switching to Retrofit anyway :)

Answer (score 29):

If you like Volley to output debug messages, you can simply set

`VolleyLog.DEBUG = true;`

then you will see all verbose log of Volley in out adb logcat output.

Comment: This is more helpful than @for3st 's answer as you don't need to run the shell command every time on a different device. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
VolleyLog.v("TAG", "Message");
```

for verbose debug option.

And to get other details you will have to try various options available with error object. Do CTRL + SPACE and go on a trial and error tour. :)

For example,

```
error.networkResponse.statusCode
```

will give the error code like 404 for page not found.

And, we can also use various Error Classes provided by Volley to check the type of error using

```
 if(error instanceOf TimeoutError ){
    // you got timed out  
 }
```

More details [here.](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/class-use/VolleyError.html) Have fun and Welcome to Android :)

Comment: Many thanks. I get a `NoConnectionError` on the emulator on my mac. The investigation continues!! :)

Answer (score 2):

What works for me as of Jan 2015 is

```
adb -s 0650ac52006b62db shell setprop Volley VERBOSE
```

"0650ac52006b62db" is the device id that you get with

```
adb devices
```

"Volley" is the name of the TAG that Volley has.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Volley logging is very limited. I needed to trace entire request/response  information, not just request url.

I ended up with **Android Studio Profiler (Network)**.

Good article that briefly describes how to enable it and what it shows https://proandroiddev.com/various-methods-to-debug-http-traffic-in-the-android-application-8685b9183418