# How to launch app on Google Glass with Voice Command

Tags: android, voice-recognition, launcher, google-glass

I've installed an application on my Google Glasses but once I've closed it, I have to connect back to my PC to start it again.

How to register my app to the list of voice commands? E.g. "Ok Glass, show me the cube". So on the main screen, you start with "OK Glass" and then say a user-defined string (for example "show me the cube") and the application that is associated with this string will launch. I've seen this before by adding a few lines into the application manifest, but can't find it again. I'm aware that this might require a rooted Glass-device, but that is ok.

[This discussion](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=6&q=voice%20command&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) is related to this question, but does not give an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple hacky ways to launch apps; I wrote a page describing them [here](http://glasswiki.org/index.php?title=Launching_Apps).

As for voice triggering, there are two things you'll need to do.

First, add the following to your manifest as a child of your `<activity>` element that you want to launch:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.glass.voice_trigger" android:resource="@string/voice_menu_trigger" />
```

and create a corresponding string in the `res/string.xml`.

Second, enable the native app voice build option on a rooted device (I describe all labs here and how to enable them [here](http://glasswiki.org/index.php?title=Google_Labs_Reference)):

```
> adb shell setprop persist.lab.native_app_voice true
```

*Note:* This will only work if your Glass is in userdebug mode. [Follow these instructions to put it into userdebug mode.](http://glasswiki.org/index.php?title=Using_Google_Labs_Features#Enabling_and_Disabling_Google_Labs_via_the_Build_Properties_File)

Comment: The meta-data element is not enough, you also need the intent-filter. I've updated your answer to reflect that.

Comment: Oh, whoops! Gotta work on my copy paste skills :) Thanks for the edit.

Comment: One more remark. The `setprop`-command works, but it does set the value in `/system/build.prop` as described here (http://glasswiki.org/index.php?title=Using_Google_Labs_Features#Enabling_and_Disabling_Google_Labs_via_the_Build_Properties_File), instead it sets a value in `/data/property/` as described here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440945/android-system-properties-unsetting-them-on-the-command-line)

Comment: Hi Alexander, thanks for the suggestion. Feel free to edit the wiki if you find it's incorrect in some regard :)

Comment: This is now broke with XE16 (or blocked I should say):  *VoiceTriggerBuildingException Custom voice triggers not allowed*